# Faces in Planar Graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx, vertices

I'm trying to find faces of an undirected planar graph.

[image: Planar Graph (Networkx random layout of vertices]

The graph is embedded in within the networkx Python Graph library and it's nodes have positions (GPS Data) such as:

```
[(0, {'pos': [12.54341, 54.10141]}), (1, {'pos': [12.5433, 54.10064]}), (2, {'pos': [12.54388, 54.10015]})...
```

.. which look like this:

[image: Graph with GPS positions]

What is the easiest way to find all "geographic" faces of the graph? With geographic I mean the cycles of the second visual presentation with start_node = end_node.

I'd appreciate a brief cookbook of how to proceed.

Comment: Have you looked at [`cycle_basis`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.cycle_basis.html#networkx.algorithms.cycles.cycle_basis)?

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Thanks Midnighter

Comment: Although this a somewhat old post, it is still the one appearing if one whats to tackle this. Thus, I feel to stress that cycle_basis of networkx does not use the coordinates of the nodes and can not find the correct faces. Additionally a the cycle basis can be found which does not correspond to the faces, right?!
My solution uses a mix of sage.graphs, since SageGraph.faces() finds the faces and setting the spatial embedding by considering the node positions first.